# Why aren't functions passed as arguments mutable like how other objects in JS are (objects, arrays)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, higher-order-functions

For example, we know that if a reference to an array gets mutated or reassigned within the scope of a function, any pointers to that data will also point to the mutated/reassigned value.

```
function arrReassigned() {
    let arr = [1,2,3];
    setTimeout(() => console.log(arr), 0);
    arr = [4,5,6];
}

function arrMutates() {
    const arr = [1,2,3];
    setTimeout(() => console.log(arr), 0);
    arr.push(4);
}

let nums = [1,2,3];

function mutateNums(nums) {
  nums.push(4);
}

arrReassigned(); // [4,5,6]
arrMutates(); // [1,2,3,4]

mutateNums(nums);
console.log(nums); // [1,2,3,4]
```

My understanding of the above:

- `arr` is initially assigned
- setTimeout is pushed and immediately popped off call stack, callback arg gets pushed into JS task queue after ~0 milliseconds
- The reference to the array gets reassigned or the value that it points to gets mutated
- Call stack is empty, so event loop pushes the callback from the task queue onto the call stack. Callback executes and references the reassigned/mutated arr variable as expected.

I tried to recreate this with function reassignment, but it doesn't behave as expected.

```
function a() {
    function b() { console.log('b') }
    setTimeout(b, 0);
    b = function() { console.log('c') }
    b();
}

a(); // logs 'c' then 'b'
```

When function `b` is passed in as an argument and eventually called via the task queue, it doesn't reference the reassigned value.

```
function a() {
    function b() { console.log('b') }
    setTimeout(() => b(), 0);
    b = function() { console.log('c') }
    b();
}

a(); // logs 'c' then 'c'
```

When we pass an anon callback into setTimeout instead, it seems to reference the reassigned function as we would expect.

What exactly is going on here? If the function is passed as an argument, why does it not reference the reassigned value like another object would (e.g. arrays).  My understanding is that a copy of the reference to the function is created when setTimeout executes, but I'm confused as to why it doesn't follow the rules of other objects when a copy of their reference is passed as arguments into a function and can then be mutated.

Comment: The *reassignment* behaviour has nothing to do with it being an (array) object. It's just a closure over a mutable variable. The same happens with a number: `let num= 1; setTimeout(() => console.log(num), 0); num = 2;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're not doing the same thing. In your `arrReassigned` function, you're passing a function into `setTimeout` that closes over `arr`. When that function runs, it sees the then-current value of `arr`.

But in your first `a` function, you're passing `b` **itself** into `setTimeout`. Then you assign `b` a new value, but that has no effect whatsoever on the value you passed into `setTimeout`.

If you make `a` the same as `arrReassigned` by passing in a function that closes over `b`, you see the result you expect:

```js
function a() {
    function b() { console.log('b') }
    setTimeout(() => b(), 0); // ***
    b = function() { console.log('c') }
    b();
}

a(); // logs 'c' then 'c'
```

There is no difference in how function objects and array objects (or any other kind of object) are handled in this regard. For instance, here's things going the other way, making `arrReassigned` not see the reassignment for the same reason your first `a` didn't:

```js
function example(a) {
    setTimeout(() => console.log(a), 0);
}
function arrReassigned() {
    let arr = [1,2,3];
    example(arr);
    arr = [4,5,6];
}

arrReassigned(); // Logs [1, 2, 3]
```

That's exactly like your first `a` function: It passes the object reference into `example`, then changes the variable that came from, which has no effect on what was passed in earlier, so `example` logs `[1, 2, 3]`.

---

The part you seem particularly to have questions about is this (the first `a`):

```
function a() {
    function b() { console.log('b') }
    setTimeout(b, 0);
    b = function() { console.log('c') }
    b();
}

a(); // logs 'c' then 'b'
```

Let's walk through what happens when you call `a`():

1. It creates a function and assigns a reference to that function to the local variable `b`. At this point, we have something like this in memory:

```
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
b: Ref54612−−−−−−>|         (function)         |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                  | name: "b"                  |
                  | [[Code]]: console.log("b") |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

The "Ref54612" is just representative, but it's useful (to me, anyway) to think of object references as numbers that tell the JavaScript engine where the object is elsewhere in memory.

2. It calls `setTimeout(b, 0);` That passes the current value of `b` into `setTimeout`, which puts that in a record in the timers list of the environment saying "call this at X time". At this point, we have something like this in memory:

```
                                +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                |                                              |
                                v                                              |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                               |
b: Ref54612−−−−−−>|         (function)         |                               |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                               |
                  | name: "b"                  |                               |
                  | [[Code]]: console.log("b") |                               |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                               |
                                                                               |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                              |
Host timer list−−>|            (list)           |                              |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
                  | 0                           |−−−−−>|    (timer info)    |  |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
                  | {callback: Ref54612, at: X} |      | callback: Ref54612 |−−+
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+      | at: X              |
                                                       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

3. It assigns a **new** function to the `b` variable. Now we have something like this:

```
                                +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                                |                                              |
                                v                                              |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                               |
                  |         (function)         |                               |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                               |
                  | name: "b"                  |                               |
                  | [[Code]]: console.log("b") |                               |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                               |
                                                                               |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                              |
Host timer list−−>|            (list)           |                              |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
                  | 0                           |−−−−−>|    (timer info)    |  |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
                  | {callback: Ref54612, at: X} |      | callback: Ref54612 |−−+
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+      | at: X              |
                                                       +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
b: Ref84965−−−−−−>|         (function)         |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                  | name: "b"                  |
                  | [[Code]]: console.log("C") |
                  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Notice how changing the value inside `b` (to "Ref84965") had no effect whatsoever on what function the timer is going to call ("Ref54612").

4. It calls `b()`, which logs `c` since that's what the new function does.

5. Later, when the host environment sees that it's time to call the function at Ref54612, it does — logging "b", since that's what that function does.

In contrasts, with your `arrReassigned` example, you passed a function (not `arr`) to `setTimeout` (since passing `arr` to it wouldn't make sense), and later when the function was run it looked up the value of `arr` **then**, and used the new array you'd assigned to it.

Comment: Why does passing `b` itself and then reassigning not have any effect? In my first example, I passed in an array itself as a function arg, pushed a value into it, and then referenced it in the global scope and it retained its mutated value.  Is there something different happening in that example vs when I passed in the function itself into `setTimeout`?

Comment: @htoor - *"In my first example, I passed in an array itself as a function arg..."* Yes, but **later**, in the `console.log` that runs when `setTimeout` calls the function. That's after the reassignment has happened. In your function example, you're using the function reference right away when you call `setTimeout`, not **later** when you call `console.log`. Since you're doing it right then, the reassignment hasn't happened, and `setTimeout` calls the old function. See my first code snippet for an equivalent with a function.

Comment: Ok let me see if my understanding is correct...so the difference between my last 2 examples is: When I pass the function itself into `setTimeout`, even though that function will only execute once our call stack is empty (and after any reassignments in the outer scope), it will still reference whatever was passed into at the exact point `setTimeout` executed.  Vs my anon function example: the arrow function executes, then tries to reference `b` which was reassigned by this point, thus it respects the reassignment

Comment: @htoor - If I understood that, yes, that's about it. I've added some diagrams above that may (or may not) help. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

What matters is when the variable is looked up to get its value. If you look up the variable in the callback function, it will get its latest value, after the reassignment.

When you do `setTimeout(b, 0)`, `b` is looked up at the time you call `setTimeout()`. That gets the original function object, and passes that to `setTimeout()`. Reassigning the variable has no effect on this.

When you do `setTimeout(() => b(), 0)`, you're passing the anonymous function to `setTimeout()`. When that function is called, it looks up `b` and gets its updated value.

Comment: So is a copy of `b` is being made when I pass it in as an argument to `setTimeout`? Or is a copy of the reference to `b` being made?

Comment: @htoor - The latter, a copy of the function reference. (This is how all objects work in JavaScript.)

Comment: Right, but I think the part after is where the confusion starts for me.  So `setTimeout` executes with b as an arg, then the reassignment of b `b = function() { console.log('c') }` executes, then b executes in the scope of `a`, then finally the `setTimeout` callback arg `b` executes.  But since the reassignment of `b` occurs before the `setTimeout` `b` argument executes, why is that argument still referring to the "old" `b`

Comment: @htoor It's a reference to the function (and this reference is held by the variable `b`, and is passed to `setTimeout`), not a reference to the variable `b`.

Comment: Thank you @Bergi! I'm positive now that I was confusing the reference to the function vs the reference to the variable.  When I pass in `b` to `setTimeout` and it executes, it creates a copy of the REFERENCE to that piece of code in memory.  Thus reassigning the original reference has no effect.  When I execute `b()` inside of the anon callback, I'm referencing the variable b which points to whatever it is assigned to at that point in time (thus respecting the reassignment).

Comment: @htoor Yes, exactly. There are no references to variables in javascript.